# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

```vb
Protected Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
        Dim medID, medName, comment As String
        Dim power, period, qtty As Integer
        'Dim nextDateOfDelivery As Date = getNextDateOfDelivery(Val(txtDays.Text))
        Dim today As System.DateTime
        Dim answer As System.DateTime
        today = System.DateTime.Now
        answer = today.AddDays(Val(txtDays.Text))
        Dim nextDateOfDelivery As Date = answer


        medName = Trim(txtMedName.Text)
        qtty = Val(txtQuantity.Text)
        comment = txtComment.Text
        power = txtPower.Text
        medID = lblMedID.Text
        period = Val(txtDays.Text)
        '............setting priorities
        '.......value of p(0) indicates priority for tablest and so on so forth.....
        Dim p() As Integer = {0, 0, 0, 0}
        For i = 0 To LBPriorities.Items.Count - 1
            Select Case LBPriorities.Items(i).Text
                Case "Tablet"
                    p(0) = i + 1
                Case "Capsule"
                    p(1) = i + 1
                Case "Liquid"
                    p(2) = i + 1
                Case "Injection"
                    p(3) = i + 1

            End Select

        Next

        '............if not available
        Dim strictlyThis As String = radNotAvailable.SelectedItem.Value
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databaseConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connStr)
        'Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        '                                       "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf;" & _
        '                                       "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

        Dim sql As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO medicine" & _
            "(medID, userID, medName, quantity, dateOfOrder, power, tabPriority, capPriority, liqPriority, " & _
            "injPriority, period, notAvailable, prescription, comment, nextDateOfDelivery)" & _
            "VALUES('" & medID & "','" & User.Identity.Name & "','" & medName & "'," & qtty & ",'" & today & "'," & power & _
            "," & p(0) & "," & p(1) & "," & p(2) & "," & p(3) & ",'" & period & "','" & strictlyThis & "', '' ,'" & comment & "','" & nextDateOfDelivery & "')", con)

        con.Open()
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()

        lblMessage.Text = "The details of the medicine have been saved. You may upload a prescription"
        FUPrescription.Enabled = True
        cmdUpload.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

this is what i am using now...but i get an error saying "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated." what does this mean???is there something wrong with my sql statement???

Comment: You're trying to put some data that doesn't fit to the column (e.g. your column is varchar(50) and you're trying to put there 100 characters.

Comment: it was varchar(50)...i cahnged it to varchar(700) still i get the error...can i save a DATE type in VArchar?

Comment: Can you paste your table create script and all the values you're trying to insert?

Comment: @Sify Juhy - "it" was `varchar(50)`? - by my count, there are 15 columns involved here. If *you've* managed to track it down to one column, which one? If you haven't, how did you know which column to alter? If you've altered all of them, and you're still getting the error, then you have some really long text in your application. Stop a debugger on the `Dim sql...` line, and inspect each variable.

Comment: @Maras http://i52.tinypic.com/2d7a89j.png  please check this link

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i suppose its `nextDateOfDelivery`

Comment: Sify, try to change all varchar columns one by one to varchar(some big number here). It should give you a chance to check which of the columns is to small for your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it was the value you're storing in dateOfOrder.

According to your screenshot, this is a VarChar(10), but you're storing `DateTime.Now.ToString()` in there, the default value of which is of the format:

```
5/1/2008 6:32:06 PM
```

Which comes in at 19 characters.

I suggest you store Dates and Times in a [more suitable field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes), such as a `Date` or `DateTime` field.

If you must store it as text, then you should at least store it in a [format that is suitable for sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx), and unambiguous, such as:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o") // Round-trip format
```

Which will give you:

```
2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000
```